# PHP SOAP WSDL list of functions

Tags: php, soap

I'm very new to soap programming and I'm stuck on something that looks very simple but I don't how to follow...

Here's my situation. I ask to wsdl soap server for a list of functions, i use `__getFunctions()` .. and I got this :

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(68) "inserirClaustreResponse inserirClaustre(inserirClaustre $parameters)" [1]=> string(56) "inserirCursResponse inserirCurs(inserirCurs $parameters)" [2]=> string(38) "loginResponse login(login $parameters)" [3]=> string(68) "inserirPropostaResponse inserirProposta(inserirProposta $parameters)" [4]=> string(71) "inserirCalendariResponse inserirCalendari(inserirCalendari $parameters)" [5]=> string(59) "inserirPreusResponse inserirPreus(inserirPreus $parameters)" [6]=> string(80) "inserirAprofitamentResponse inserirAprofitament(inserirAprofitament $parameters)" [7]=> string(62) "inserirAlumneResponse inserirAlumne(inserirAlumne $parameters)" [8]=> string(62) "inserirHorariResponse inserirHorari(inserirHorari $parameters)" [9]=> string(41) "logoutResponse logout(logout $parameters)" }
```

if I use `__getTypes()`, I got this :

```
[13]=> string(52) "struct LoginInfo { string password; string user; }"
```

Ok, when I do `$client->login(array('password'=>'pass', 'user'=>'admin'));`

If I do a `__getLastRequest()`

I see this on my request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:ns1="http://***masked***.net">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:login>
<ns1:in0 xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns1:login>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I can't see password and user inside `<ns1:login>` ... I'm not getting and error, but the server is not accepting because there is no data in function login...

Comment: Any chance that you can post the pertinent parts of the wsdl - the parts that define the above functions?

Comment: edited with var_dump of __getFunctions() :

Comment: and url is http://preproduccio.www14.gencat.cat/jov_titus/AppJava/services/EscolesWebService?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array for the parameter you should build a class which represents the requestparameters as attributes:

```
class Login{
 public $password;
 public $user;

 function __construct() {
  $this->password = "pass";
  $this->user = "admin";
 }
}
```

And then initialize the class and add the object as paramter to the soap-request:

```
$login = new Login();
$client->login(array($login));
```